# TWIG - Include different JS asset file depending to a variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I would like to load different JavaScript files in a Twig template depending to a variable setup before.

And i try to do something like that :

```
{% set myFileToLoad = 'awesomeScript.js' %}

{% javascripts
    'js/forms/' ~ myFileToLoad
%}
    <script  src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But I got this error each time I try to edit the name of the asset :

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getFilename" of class "Twig\TokenStream".

Is there a way to do it better ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using an old syntax based on the [assetic bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files) that is no longer supported on Symfony >= 4.0, but you can use standard blocks instead, and are pretty close to getting it right:

```
{% set myFileToLoad = 'awesomeScript.js' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/forms/' ~ myFileToLoad) }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, we are on Symfony 3.4 so we still use this syntax. When I try to use the twig asset() function, it return the real path (js/forms/myfile.js) and not the compiled path that I need..

Comment: what u mean with compiled path?